# Extraer caracteres de una cadena JSON en MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

extraigo los ids de una cadena JSON en una tabla a travez de un query de Mysql

```sql
    SELECT work_workers , JSON_EXTRACT(work_workers,'$[*].id') AS workers FROM work_orders
```

Obtengo las IDs ["121", "109", "27"], mi pregunta es como puedo quitarle los corchetes, las comillas y que cada ID quede en una fila para posteriormente hacer un INNER JOIN con otra tabla y obtener datos utilizando los IDs. de antemano Gracias

Comment: Puedes usar una regex (expresión regular) para machearlo y luego un replace del carácter Machado

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que lo puedes lograr con la función `REPLACE` usándola doble vez:

- El primer llamado a la función para eliminar el corchete del inicio
- El segundo llamado a la función para eliminar el corchete del final

Como el resultado es un *array* le indicamos que inicie desde la posición 0 y termine en la última posición existente por eso el uso del *

Te anexo este ejemplo:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT('[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]', '$[*]'), "[", ""), "]", "") AS Limpia;
```

Con una salida así:

```
SinCrochetes
2, 4, 6, 8, 10
```

Ahora si quieres eliminar las comillas dobles de cada uno de los números, prueba con tu `SELECT` compuesto de un `REPLACE` mas de este modo:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT('["2", "4", "6", "8", "10"]', '$[*]'), "[", ""), "]", ""), '"', '');
```

Con una salida asi:

```
SinCrochetes
2, 4, 6, 8, 10
```

**Referencias**

- [JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract)
- [REPLACE FUNCIÓN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Comment: Perfecto, ya modifique el query con la funcion REPLACE quedando de esta manera
```sql
SELECT work_number , REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(work_workers,'$[*].id'),"[",""),"]",""),'"','') AS workers FROM work_orders
```
me arroja los numeros sin caracteres pero ahora lo que necesito es que se forme una fila por cada numero por ejemplo pasar de esto
work_number       workers
10014                   110,130 
a esto:
work_number       workers
10014                   110
10014                   130

Comment: me funciono perfecto el tema que tengo es de que me arroje un ID por cada fila

Comment: El tema es que cada numero de la columna workers es un ID que necesito utilizar para hacer una consulta con INNER JOIN a otra tabla

Comment: En este caso siento y opino que ya queda demasiado rebuscado el resultado que buscas (el cual comprendo), lo que mejor te puedo recomendar es que con tu lenguaje de backend asignes este resultado a una variable y posteriormente pases esto en una nueva consulta donde estos valores ya los puedes aplicar en el uso del JOIN, salvo los aportes de otros usuarios

Comment: con PHP lo puedo hacer el problema es que son demasiados registros y la consulta tarda demasiado, por eso quiero hacerlo directamente haciendo la consulta por sql